# Is it possible to argue that $\nabla F(x^{*})\neq \textbf{0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. For every affine subset $L$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ of the form
\begin{eqnarray}
L=\{{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}:A{x}=b\}
\end{eqnarray}
for some $m\times n$ matrix $A$ having full rank and $b\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, with $m\leq n$, it is known that $F$ attains a $\textbf{unique minimum}$ (let's call it $x^{*}$) over $L$. Further, it is known that $F$ attains a unique minimum on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ itself. Let's call this point as $x^{0}$.

Given $L\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ of the above form satisfying

1. $x^{0}\notin L$, and
2. $x^{*}\in L$ is the unique point where $F$ attains a minimum in $L$,

we know, from Lagrange's theorem, that there exists $\lambda^{*}\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla F(x^{*})=A^{T}\lambda^{*}.
\end{eqnarray}

Is it possible to argue that $\nabla F(x^{*})=A^{T}\lambda^{*}\neq \textbf{0}$, the all-zero vector? If so, can someone provide a proof of the same?

Since $F$ attains a global minimum at $x^{0}$, it is clear that 
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla F(x^{0})=\textbf{0}.
\end{eqnarray}

Since $x^{0}$ is the global minimum, my question is if it is possible that $\nabla F(x^{*})=\textbf{0}$ for $x^{*}\neq x^{0}$ that is the unique point of minimum in $L$.

Nothing more is known about the function $F$, except that it is differentiable. Can imposing more constraints on $F$ (such as requiring $F$ to be strictly convex) pave way for arguing that $\nabla F(x^{*})$ should be a non-zero vector?

---

**Add 1**: If we are told that $\nabla F(x^{*})=\textbf{0}$ for some $x^{*}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, then we may not be able to conclude if $x^{*}$ is a point of minimum or maximum (or even saddle). However, knowing apriori the fact that $x^{*}$ is the unique point in $L$ where $F$ attains a minimum, and that $x^{0}$ is the unique point in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $F$ attains a minimum, isn't it reasonable to say $\nabla F(x^{*})\neq \textbf{0}$? For, if it were $\textbf{0}$, there would be two points (namely $x^{*}$ and $x^{0}$) where $F$ attains minima in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$? This is just a thought.

Comment: If it is true, the key property here must be that $F$ attains a *unique* minimum on each hyperplane. Otherwise it need not be true.

Comment: @Surb yes I too feel this is the point that must be exploited to the fullest. But I do not find a way to argue to my satisfaction.

Comment: By the way, in the case $n=1$, the set $L$ is a single point and not an interval isn't it?

Comment: @Surb that's right. The intervals don't map to $L$ directly, but I just had a picture like $F(x)=x^{2}$ for a function which attains a minimum on every interval. That's why I wrote "something similar" in the question. Sorry if it is misguiding

Comment: Probably the best way to start is with a strictly convex function. Have you checked if such mappings satisfy your assumptions?

Comment: @Karthik - The function $f(x)=x^2$ is not a good example. The conditions are quite different. In fact, do you have a proper example?

Comment: @uniquesolution sorry for the example, if it is misleading. I've been finding it difficult to visualize a function that attains a unique minimum on every $L$ as mentioned in the question, but is not strictly decreasing, strictly increasing or strictly convex.

Comment: The condition for complimentary slackness wont allow all $\lambda^*$ to be zero

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan Can you be a bit more specific? Do you mean that there exists $\lambda^{*}$ from Lagrange's theorem that satisfies $A^{T}\lambda^{*}\neq \textbf{0}$?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan this is true provided that you can show that $x^*$ is always attained at the boundary, isn't?

Comment: @Karthik -- If you are having difficulties coming up with a single example, then the problem is not interesting.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan There is no complementary slackness for *equalities*.

Comment: @Surb. That would be correct. For convex functions, this would be a direct consequence from the gradient inequality

Comment: @uniquesolution For example, $F(x)=||x||^{2}$ satisfies the required property (that it should attain a minimum over every $L$ of the form mentioned in the question). This is why I drew the analogy with $F(x)=x^{2}$ for the one dimensional case. But I am still trying to come up with one more example as this.

Comment: @Karthik Thanks, that's a start. It seems that functions of the form $f(||x||)$ for suitable $f$  will also serve as examples.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, for example, monotone functions of $||x||$ would also serve as examples.

Comment: @A.G. good point, but can't every equality be rewritten as a pair of inequalities?

Comment: @Surb It is always a bad thing to do, because the inequality gradients are going to violate the constraint qualification for sure, and the KKT theory is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that $\nabla F(\mathbf x^*)=0$ for $\mathbf x^*\ne \mathbf x^0$.

**Example**: take $f(t)=(t-1)^3$ and consider $F(x,y)=f(x^2+y^2)$. Basically, the graph of $F$ is the rotation of the following curve

[image]

The level sets of $F$ are circles, hence, the minimum on any line is unique (intersections of circles and tangent lines are unique). However, the equation
$$
\nabla F(x,y)=2 f'(x^2+y^2)\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=0
$$
has several solutions: the origin (the global minimum of $F$) and the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ where $f'=0$. Hence, taking $L=\{y=1\}$, for example, will give $\mathbf x^*=(0,1)\ne \mathbf x^0=(0,0)$ with $\nabla F(\mathbf x^*)=0$.

The condition that $F$ attains unique minimum on all linear manifolds is equivalent to the level subsets $\{F(\mathbf x)\le C\}$ being strictly convex, that makes $F$ necessarily strictly [quasiconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function). If we strengthen it to be [pseudoconvex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoconvex_function) (or, in particular, convex) then 
$$
\nabla F(a)=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad a\text{ is the global minimum}
$$
and by uniqueness it can happen only at $x^0$.

Comment: Wow!! This is a great answer! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "The condition that F attains unique minimum on all linear manifolds is equivalent to the level subsets {F(x)≤C} being strictly convex, that makes F necessarily strictly quasiconvex"? Any hints on how I can prove this to myself by merely using the fact that F attains a unique minimum on every linear (affine) manifold?

Comment: @Karthik I do not have a short proof, just idea: if the minimum is unique then the level subsets $\{F(x)\le \min+\epsilon\}$ should be homotopy equivalent to a point (aka *contractible*). If such a set is not convex then the convex hull is not strictly convex, and there is a supporting hyperplane that meets it at more than one point which contradicts the uniqueness of  minimum. If a level subset $\{F(x)\le C\}$ for an arbitrary $C$ is not contractible then as $C\to\min$ it should bifurcate to a contractible set, and when the bifurcation happens we get again the same contradiction as above.

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you so much